# newbie SQL Question regarding computed columns

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns Q1 and Q2 say. I now want to define a view such that I have three columns in in Q1 Q2 and H1 such that each entry in H1 is the sum of corresponding entries Q1 and Q1

How can I do this as as SQL Query?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouyld try this :

```
CREATE VIEW Q1Q2H1 AS
SELECT Q1,Q2,Q1+Q2 as H1
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE VIEW ComputedColumn AS
SELECT Q1, Q2, Q1 + Q2 AS H1
  FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  Q1, Q2, Q1 + Q2 AS H1
FROM
  table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Q1, Q2, Q1 + Q2 AS H1 FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Q1 and Q2 are numeric types, this should do:

```
CREATE VIEW SumView
AS
SELECT Q1, Q2, Q1 + Q2 AS H1
FROM MyTable
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT Q1, Q2, Q1 + Q2 as H1 FROM Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
CREATE VIEW [MyView]
AS
SELECT     Q1, Q2, Q1 + Q2 AS H1
FROM       MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

All good answers, but I'd consider having a computed column on the table if your RDBMS supports it.

Eg For [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx)

```
ALTER TABLE Mytable ADD H1 AS Q1 + Q2
```

Now it's available in all queries on this table (stored proc, triggers etc) and for constraints